# Cannot login to admin page umbraco backoffice

Tags: umbraco

I have created an Umbraco version 7.10 project. I can  access the umbraco backoffice when I debug the project locally however when I deploy this to server, I cannot access umbraco backoffice.

The web address returns : http://testweb.santamonicafly.com/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fumbraco

404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

I tried to check the login page in project directory.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="yourAuthCookie" loginUrl="login.aspx" protection="All" path="/" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <allow users="?" />
</authorization>
<!-- Membership Provider -->
<membership defaultProvider="UmbracoMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" type="Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers.MembersMembershipProvider, Umbraco" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" minRequiredPasswordLength="10" useLegacyEncoding="false" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" defaultMemberTypeAlias="Member" passwordFormat="Hashed" allowManuallyChangingPassword="false" />
    <add name="UsersMembershipProvider" type="Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers.UsersMembershipProvider, Umbraco" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

I am working on this to get access to admin page so that people can update the content of website.

Answer (score 1):

Umbraco Umbraco back office has a default URL /Umbraco, like in your case: http://testweb.santamonicafly.com/umbraco